# Adding Docker’s official GPG key on a ubuntu VM fails

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Hello all i am trying to add the official GPGkey to my ubuntu VM but it fails with the following error :

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: download.docker.com
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

the command I use is the following:

```
root@ubuntu1804:~# curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
```

the curl output alone is working and my resolv.conf file is fine I have internet access :

```
root@ubuntu1804:~# curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=0YYh
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

my release is ubuntu bionic :

```
root@ubuntu1804:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

my resolv.conf:

````
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 8.8.8.8
options edns0
search lan
```

So What am I missing exactly ?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IPv4 for `curl` and `apt` for `download.docker.com` to be resolved
correctly.

In curl, add the `-4` argument:

```
$ curl -4fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

To force apt to use IPv4 see the article
[Force Apt-Get to IPv4 or IPv6 on Ubuntu or Debian](https://www.vultr.com/docs/force-apt-get-to-ipv4-or-ipv6-on-ubuntu-or-debian).

It would perhaps be simpler to turn off IPv6 in your local network.

Comment: bull's eye thank you I completely forgot about this